# Google adsense not showing on other computers (test with localhost)

Tags: localhost, mamp, adsense

I am developping a website and I test it with MAMP. In this website, I have to show google adsense adds. They are displaying on my computer, but when my coworkers tested it on their computer with [localhost ip]:8888/, the blocks which are supposed to whos adds display blank blocks. I don't understand because on my computer, that works properly, the ads are blank only on the other computers.

Could someone tell me why it shows blank adds and what is the solution please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally Google Adsense is now binded to a web address. (e.g. http://www.test.com. Perhaps just use an entry in /etc/hosts to access localhost via the right url. In this case an entry in hosts file with www.test.com 127.0.0.1 should to the trick